# Symfony 2 Apache 2.4 php7 ugrade Vhost file

Tags: symfony, virtualhost, php-7, apache2.4

My server was hacked I was left with no option other than to create a new server in doing so I upgraded to latest Apache 2.4 and PHP 7 now unfortunately I find my Symofony 2 app does not work I am having issues with the Vhost configuration.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help in updating the vhost file and also specify if there are any php mods I need to install to replace the old php 5 mods on the original vhost file.

This is the original vhost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin contact@example.net
    ServerName apps.example.com    ServerAlias www.apps.example.com    
    DocumentRoot /home/example.com.v2.0/Symfony2/web/
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example-apps-live-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example-apps-live-access_log combined

    HostnameLookups Off

    UseCanonicalName Off

    ServerSignature On

    <Directory "/home/example.com.v2.0/Symfony2/web/">
        #Require all granted
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Includes +ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            AddHandler fcgid-script .php
            FCGIWrapper /home/php-fcgi-starter .php
        AcceptPathInfo On
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all    
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommended this config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName      mi-sitio.com
ServerAlias     www.mi-sitio.com

SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER     "..."
SetEnv SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD "..."

DocumentRoot    "/Proyectos/Symfony2/mi-sitio.com/web"
DirectoryIndex  app.php

<Directory "/Proyectos/Symfony2/mi-sitio.com/web">
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

CustomLog  /var/log/httpd/mi-sitio.com-access.log combined

KeepAlive            On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
KeepAliveTimeout     5

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                  "application/javascript" \
                                  "application/json" \
                                  "application/rss+xml" \
                                  "application/x-javascript" \
                                  "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                  "application/xml" \
                                  "image/svg+xml" \
                                  "text/css" \
                                  "text/html" \
                                  "text/javascript" \
                                  "text/plain" \
                                  "text/xml"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif    "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png    "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg   "now plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

You can read the doc and generate your config at http://symfony.es/documentacion/como-configurar-bien-apache-para-las-aplicaciones-symfony2/

Answer (score 0):

Order allow,deny

This doesn't exist anymore.

```
   Using mod_php/PHP-CGI with Apache 2.4¶

 In Apache 2.4, Order Allow,Deny has been replaced by Require all
 granted. Hence, you need to modify your Directory permission settings
 as follows: 

 <Directory /var/www/project/public>
     Require all granted
     # ... </Directory>
```

Check the official doc of symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html